# URL Rewrite all broken

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am in a crisis at the moment, i overwrote my .htaccess file which had a lot of URL Rewrites that I did 6 months ago.  Now I have to redo them all because I can't get half of my website to work without it.

I have a list of things I need to change, maybe they all use the same method, maybe some of them don't, here is a quick list...

```
Old: http://i.website.com/(Anything)
New: http://www.website.com/images/(Anything)
```

Then after I need to make this:

```
Old: http://www.website.com/images/(Anything)
New: http://www.website.com/images.php?id=(Anything)
```

Errr, these are the two main ones to start me off...i really need these asap, i have over 100k images offline at the moment because these links are broken :(

Thanks

EDIT:

Also I have this at the bottom of my htaccess for my framework:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I need the second rewrite Rule (the images.php one) to skip this rule and not use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^i.website.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.website.com/images/$1 [R]

RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ /images.php?id=$1 [L]
```

First entry checks the requested host is `i.website.com` and redirects `[R]` to the new URL.  The next checks if the requested host is `www.website.com`, then matches anything in the `images/` path and rewrites the URL as you requested, the `[L]` tells it to do no further processing.

Follow that with the catch-all rule you mentioned to redirect other enquiries to your framework.